Solving $ \sqrt{-4 + \sqrt{8 +{16 \over \sin^{4}\left(x\right)} + \sin^{4}\left(x\right)}} = \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{6} $
THE QUESTION:
$$
\sqrt{-4 +
\sqrt{8 +{16 \over \sin^{4}\left(x\right)} + \sin^{4}\left(x\right)}} =
\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{6}
$$

I tried using brute force to simplify this instead of using some manipulation.
Squaring on both sides and transposing terms to simplify, which leads to
$$
\sqrt{8 + {16 \over \sin^{4}\left(x\right)} + \sin^{4}\left(x\right)} = \frac{73}{12}
$$
Again squaring and simplifying, results in
$$
16 + \sin^{8}\left(x\right) = {4177 \over 144}\sin^{4}\left(x\right)
$$
After this, how to find the value of $x$ ( in degrees ) ?,

Any hint or manipulation tricks would be useful$\ldots$ ( even full solution is also okay ).
Thank you in advance

Did you try the sub $u=\sin^4 x$ ?

@SineoftheTime yes i did that.. but still it is a big expression which is hard to simplify.
ig the method which is used is itself wrong. we need to simplify in different way
U is coming as some big expression with srqt and big denominator

By solving the equation $144x^2-4177x+2304=0$ where $x=\sin^4x$, we have $$x_1=\frac{9}{16},x_2=\frac{256}{9}$$

@riteshwar Instead of squaring, you can take square roots, like this $\sqrt{4 + \sqrt{8 + \frac{16}{\sin^{4}x} + \sin^{4}x}} = \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{{\left( \sin^{2}x + \frac{4}{\sin^{2}x} \right)}^{2}}} = \sqrt{4 + \sin^{2}x + \frac{4}{\sin^{2}x}} = \sqrt{{\left(\sin x + \frac{2}{\sin x}\right)}^{2}}$. Then there are two cases to work on: $\sin x + \frac{2}{\sin x} = \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{6}$ and $\sin x + \frac{2}{\sin x} = -\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{6}$.

but in both these case there is no real values of x ( as when I solve the quadratic I am getting discriminant as negative entity)

nvm instead of $-4$ u wrote $4$ so only its wrong...
instead of $(a+b)^2 $ we have to use $(a-b)^2$

I don't believe squaring is necessary.  Note that what's inside the first square root is equal to $(\sin^2x)^2+2(\sin^2x)(\frac{4}{\sin^2x})+(\frac4{\sin^2x})^2=(\sin^2x+\frac4{\sin^2x})^2$.  I believe you'll also be able to simplify the outer square root, but be a little more careful.  For the inner square root, $\sin^2x+\frac4{\sin^2x}$ is clearly positive.  For the outer square root, there may be more than 1 case.

Noticing that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{6} & =\sqrt{-4+\sqrt{8+\frac{16}{\sin ^4 x}+\sin ^4 x}}\\&=\sqrt{-4+\sqrt{\left(\sin ^2 x+\frac{4}{\sin ^2 x}\right)^2}} \\
& =\sqrt{-4+\sin ^2 x+\frac{4}{\sin ^2 x}} \\
& =\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{\sin x}-\sin x\right)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
we have
$$
\frac{2}{\sin x}-\sin x= \pm \frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{6} \Leftrightarrow x=2 \pi n \pm \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
$$
where $n\in \mathbb Z$.
Wish it helps.

this doesn't seem right... or perhaps not fully simplified... when solving for quadratic equation u will end with 2 solutions and one of them simplifies to $x=60$
